# Integer arithmetic on floating points

Tags: assembly, x86-64, sse, cpu-registers

I have a floating point value in an xmm register and I heve to do some integer arithmetic on it. By integer arithmetic I mean bit-manipulation like shift or bit-wise and/or/xor. In C++, I can write something like:

```
float x;
int& x_i = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&x);
x_i &= 0x7f800000
x_i >>= 23;
x_i %= 2;
x_i <<= 23;
```

When compiled with gcc, this will copy the value in xmm0 onto the stack, then load the same from the stack onto a general register (eax), do there the integer arithmetic and finally copy eax -> stack -> xmm.

My question is wether there is a method for doing all these operations without passing through the stack. Does x86_64 have an intruction for copying the content of xmm0 to eax or some other general register?

EDIT: the question itself changed during the discussion. There are two final remarks, in both of which I refer to the corresponding sections of the [Intel C++ Intrisics Reference](http://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/9/4/c/8/e/18072-347603.pdf).

1. One can move data between general purpose regiters and XMM registers using intrinsics (sections "Steaming SIMD Extensions -> Conversion Operations for Streaming SIMD Extensions" and "Steaming SIMD Extensions 2 -> Integer Intrinsics -> Integer Move Operations for Streaming SIMD Extensions 2")
2. One can perform integer aritmetic (e.g. bit-manipulation) operations on XMM registers (section "Steaming SIMD Extensions 2 -> Integer Intrinsics)

Both of these topics are of particular interest for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised gcc involves the stack at all. At least for the ELF (SysV) ABI, the first floating-point argument will be passed by register in `%xmm0`.

If I understand you correctly, you want to move the floating-point value into a 32-bit GPR for bitwise manipulation. You can accomplish this with the `movd` instruction:

```
movd %xmm0, %eax
```

In C, you can look at the assembly output for:

```
#include <immintrin.h> /* or older: <xmmintrin.h> */
...
unsigned int x_i;
*((float *) & ret) = _mm_cvtss_f32(v0);
```

You would obviously replace this cast with the C++ reinterpret_cast.

---

To write back to the SSE register: `movd %eax, %xmm0`, which zero-extends bits 32..127 of `%xmm0`.

Comment: I think the XMM registers are happy to do boolean/bit math.  Can't he just do the operations there?  (He might have to escape to assembly code to do it).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'll try as soon as I have some time. As I said, GCC actually passes through the stack even when I compile with -O3.

Comment: Ira Baxter: I did not find any instruction for performing bit manipulation in xmm registers, but this does not mean that they do not exist :-)  Are you aware of the intrinsics or instructions for doing that?

Comment: There are plenty intrinsics for boolean math:
and = _mm_and_si128
shr = _mm_srli_epi32
Mod2 = and with immediate 1
shl = _mm_slli_epi32

Comment: @Spiros - it occurs to me you're manipulating the exponent. Don't forget the [exponent bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#Exponent_encoding). Perhaps if you described what you are trying to do, it might be possible to perform the manipulation in the `xmm` register itself.

Comment: @Vlad Krasnov: I did not know there were such intrinsics. Could you please link to a reference? That would be great.

Comment: @Brett Hale: indeed, one of my goals is to do some operations depending on the (biased) exponent. I'm considering the effect of the bias, of course, but thanks for pointing out. Anyway, I'm doing a lot of such operations. E.g. indexing a lookup table using the last 3 indices of the exponent and the first 4 of the mantissa.

Comment: @Spiros: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions#Integer_instructions and the Intel instruction manuals for details. (The claim is that early SSE instructions sets didn't have integer ops; but later ones do, and pretty much every Intel/AMD chip that I know about has all this stuff).